# Getting multiple MySQL Query results on Visual C# Console App

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am trying to print out results from a MySQL query on a Visual C# Console application. I am able to get multiple columns on one line as you can see below, but I am wondering how I can get multiple results (rows). You see, my table holds more records that meet the query criteria. Can someone help me out?

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string ConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Database=world; Uid=root; Pwd=password"; // giving connection string
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString); 
        MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand(); 
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name, population FROM city where population > 4000000"; 

        try 
        { 
        connection.Open(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("City name is: " + reader["name"].ToString() + " " + reader["population"].ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is the Console.Read() really wanted in the while loop ? You know this blocks waiting for user input ? Is this maybe why you only see one result ?

Comment: You're correct, can you respond formally so I can accept your question? It's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to Console.Read() is blocking the while loop, so you're only printing one line to console, and then waiting for user input.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You want to remove that `Console.Read();`, it is *blocking* your application from continuing on until it reads another character input on the Console.

Other things to consider: [`Using statements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) ensure that the unmanaged resources consumed by the *MySql objects* are released when the objects are no longer in use. Use [`Parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) (aka Prepared Statements) as they performs better and are more secure.

```
   string sql = "SELECT name, population FROM city WHERE population > @population"
   using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(/*Connection String*/))
   { 
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd  = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@population", 4000000);
             using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
             {
                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                      Console.WriteLine("City: {0} Population: {1}", 
                                       reader["name"], reader["population"]);
                 }
             }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be other ways to do this, but the best way that I know of is loading the datareader into a datatable.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("City");
dt.Fill(reader);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows){
  Console.WriteLine("City name is: " + row["name"].ToString() + " " + row["population"].ToString());
  Console.Read();
}
```

**EDIT** While answering, I realized that the Console.Read() may be the issue. This code will work, but an input to the console will need to be given for each line.